# javascript - Array values in <li></li>

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i display my array values in `<li></li>`

My code :

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navp">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
    var myList = [ 
    ['1','one'],
    ['1','two'],
    ['1','three'],
    ];
for (var tok in myList) { console.log(tok, myList[tok][1]); }
```

I want to display `one, two, three` in list (`<li></li>`).

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  You seem to be able to loop through the array.  Do you just not know how to edit DOM elements?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML and http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-dom-intro/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With HTML:**

```
<ul id="navp">
</ul>
```

**Try these JS codes:**

```
var myList = [ 
    ['1','one'],
    ['1','two'],
    ['1','three'],
    ];

var mainList = document.getElementById("navp");

for(var i=0;i<myList.length;i++){
         var item = myList[i];
         var elem = document.createElement("li");
         elem.value=item[0];
         elem.innerHTML=item[1];

         mainList.appendChild(elem);
    }
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Tf4ky/)

Comment: I don't think `<li>` elements have a `.value` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

One possible way:

```
var li = document.getElementById("navp").getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0, len = li.length; i < len; i++) {
    li[i].innerHTML = myList[i][1];
}
```

Another way is to use modern [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var li = document.querySelectorAll("#navp > li");
for (var i = 0, len = li.length; i < len; i++) {
    li[i].innerHTML = myList[i][1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like, dynamically depend on length of array push li tags

```
const emailList = [];
data.invalidEmailIds.forEach((email) => {
 emailList.push("<li>" + email + "</li>");
});
```

In html , just you can use {{emailList}}